# Login in asp.net using rest api and angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have created a login page in ASP.NET using AngularJS and REST API,
but I don't know how to created?

How to perform the login operation in ASP.NET using AngularJS and REST API with an auto-generate Token.

Answer (score 0):

Design form as below

```
  <div class="form-box" id="login-box">
        <div class="header">Sign In</div>
        <form>
            <div class="body bg-gray">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="userid" ng-model="login.user_user" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="login.user_pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
                </div>          
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me"/> Remember me
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">                                                               
                <button type="submit" class="btn bg-olive btn-block" ng-click="doLogin(login)">Sign me in</button>  


            </div>
        </form>


    </div>
```

And in controller

```
//Controller to login
app.controller('login', function ($scope) {
  //initially set those objects to null to avoid undefined error
  $scope.doLogin               = {};
  logdata                      = {};


  $scope.doLogin  = function (logdata) {

                  $http.post('urltopost').then(function(result){
                        if(result.data.flag==1)
                        {
                            window.location = "home.html";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          alert('Wrong username and password!');
                        }

                  });


  };



});
```

Comment: But how to generate tokan?